# To replace more than one empty string with "+" using pyautogui

Tags: python, replace, pyautogui

I learned how to replace empty characters with "+".

```
search_term ='test     test1  test2'
search_term = "+".join(search_term.split())
print(search_term)
```

Result, it works
test+test1+test2

Use "pyautogui" to obtain input strings.

```
import urllib
import pyautogui

btn_search_term = pyautogui.prompt(title='input', default='',
                                   text='search_term')
search_term = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(btn_search_term)
search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
search_term = "+".join(search_term.split())
print('search_term', search_term)
```

Result,
search_term: test+++++test1++test2

I gave the same input to the prompt window "test     test1  test2"
How do I get the same result with the input Pyautogui?

Comment: remove the line `search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are replacing every blank space with the "+" sign, the best solution here would be using the [Regex Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), if you use a Regex then you can replace any number of subsequent blank space by a single "+" sign, the code would look like this:

```py
import re

search_term ='test     test1  test2'

output = re.sub('\s+','+', search_term)

print(output)
```

output:

```py
test+test1+test2
```

I think this should solve your problem.